# Android.Фрагменты(переключение)

Tags: android, fragmenttabhost, android-fragment

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане.
Использую фрагменты и табы.
Фрагменты переключаются с помощью viewPager и фрагментадаптера для него.
Возникла проблема с фрагментом на котором реализована камера:
У меня 5 фрагментов, фрагмент с камерой посредине(3ий), так вот если я после него переключаюсь на второй или четвертый, то surfaceview остается видима и на них!(без камеры, просто черное место)
Но если переключаюсь на 1ый и последний, то всё отлично скрывается
Проследил лайфцикл, при первом и последний вызывается онСтоп онПауз и т.д. у рагента с камерой, а при соседних фрагментах нет
Не трудно понять ,что это сделано для быстроты переключения между ближайшими фрагментами

Так как мне это убрать?Чтобы и при переключении соседних тоже вызывались онСтоп и он Пауз

Пробовал вручную их вызывать, не помогает...
Так же читал про метод addToBactStack(), который вроде может помочь.Но его надо вызывать при переключении, а этим занимается адаптер у себя внутри

Помогите пожалуйста, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

[`ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)). Выставление значения в 0 даст вам желаемый результат.

Comment: увы не всегда в таких случаях помогает хотя при больших объемах об этом не стоит забывать

Answer (score 0):

Имел схожую проблему когда в каждой вкладке таба был свой viewPager.  Когда работаете с viewPager  фрагменты не уничтожаются, метод onDestroy не вызывается.
Решил довольно топорно, но у меня было всего два таба и соответственно памяти на мой костыль тратилось не критично. Использовал два viewPager и расположил   их в одном frame, просто меняя их размер.

Comment: Хм, а мб не использовать вьюПейджер вообще. Мб самому заменять фрагменты...попробую как я

Comment: Случайно нашёл элемент FragmentTabHost, он меня спас)